# TextColor of button is not changing onclick of parent LinearLayout

Tags: android

I want to change the textcolor of button and modify image when I click on its parent linear layout.
Image is changing but textcolor is not getting changed on click of linear layout.

**Here is my code in xml** -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/done_with_accounts_action"
            android:textColor="@drawable/done_button_text_selector"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/done_button_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/done_btn_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/done_btn_arrow_bg_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

**selector xml for button -**

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/done_btn_pressed_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/done_btn_pressed_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/button_text_white_color" />
</selector>
```

If I replace button with TextView, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution -
I have to set clickable as false for the done button.Now it also recognizes its parent onClick event.

Why the above code worked with textView because its onClick event is disabled byDefault, so it recognizes its parent onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

In this lines:

```
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/done_btn_pressed_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/done_btn_pressed_color" />
```

You put the same color `done_btn_pressed_color`.
Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: No this is not the problem.As default color is different.

Comment: I tried.I can not set it to linear layout as there are two different xml selectors for button [change textcolor] and imageview[change image].And changing on button layout does not help.